# Linux: Merging data from two different files into one, how is it done?

Tags: linux, bash

I have two files, one is filled with ip's, one ip in a line and another file called hosts which holds the resolve names for the ip's in the ip's file.
I'm trying to create a hosts file and so i'm trying to take first line from the ip's file and then insert a blank and then the resolve host from the hosts file and do the same for each one of the ip/hosts.
What would be the best way to achieve that goal?

The ip's file looks like this:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
```

The hosts file looks like this:

```
server01
server02
server03
server04
```

Comment: Please post some example input so we can guess solutions in a less theoretical way.

Comment: If the lines correspond in each file you can just use `paste ip_file host_file`

Comment: @SeanBright is right, but just include the --delimiter option as well `paste --delimiters=' ' ip_file host_file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume both are in order, in which case you need the program called `paste`.
Something like:

```
paste -d" " ips.txt names.txt
```

Comment: I would even delete the `-d`, as the default is TAB and it's the one normally used in `/etc/hosts`.